Count tag usage given set of other tags
I'm writing a filtering mechanism for my tag system. What I'm having trouble is getting tag use count when given a set of some tags. I'll explain my setup first.
I have two main tables: tags and item_tags. First one stores tag: ID and name, second one assigns tags to some items using two columns: IDitem and IDtag.
Filtering mechanism allows the user to select any set of tags and is supposed to display all items that are tagged with all of the selected tags.
Example database
CREATE TABLE `tags`(ID int, name text);
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES 
    (1, "food"),
    (2, "fruit"), 
    (3, "drink"),
    (4, "absurdly_sweet"),
    (5, "car");

CREATE TABLE `item_tags`(IDitem int, IDtag int);
INSERT INTO `item_tags` VALUES 
    (1, 1), (1, 2), -- Apple
    (2, 1), (2, 3), -- Apple juice
    (3, 5),  -- A car
    (4, 2), (4, 5), -- Apple-shaped car
    (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4); -- Sweet drink

For example, if user selects "fruit" and "drink" tags, filtering system should display items 2 (Apple juice) and 5 (Sweet drink), because both items are tagged as both "fruit" and "drink".
Counting tag usage
To get all tags with the number of items tagged with them I can use either query:
SELECT t.ID, t.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_tags it WHERE it.IDtag=t.ID) as `count` FROM tags t;
SELECT t.ID, t.name, COUNT(it.IDtag) AS `count` FROM tags t LEFT JOIN item_tags it ON it.IDtag=t.ID GROUP BY t.ID;

Getting tagged items
To get all items tagged with a specific set of tags (in this example, with tags "1" and "3"), I can use:
SELECT it.IDitem
FROM `item_tags` it
LEFT JOIN `tags` t
ON t.ID=it.IDtag
WHERE it.IDtag IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY it.IDitem
HAVING COUNT(*)=2 -- <- Must match number of tags we're looking for

Getting tag usage given a set of tags
What I'm struggling with is getting the tag usage. When filtering, I want to display a list of items with specified tags, all of the tags and their count in the resulting list.
For example, when searching for tags "1/food" and "3/drink", user should see:

Items:

2: Apple juice #food #drink
5: Sweet drink #food #drink #absurdly_sweet

Tags:

1: food [2]
2: fruit [0]
3: drink [2]
4: absurdly_sweet [1]
5: car [0]


Getting the numbers in square brackets is the main problem I'm facing.
Initially I tried to get all tags and run a subquery that would count items tagged with (t.ID, 1, 3), but it seems that correlated queries can only go one level down:
SELECT t.ID, t.name, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM (
        SELECT it.IDitem
        FROM `item_tags` it
        WHERE it.IDtag IN (t.ID, 1, 3)
        GROUP BY it.IDitem
        HAVING COUNT(*)=2
        ) subcount
    ) AS `count`
FROM tags t

Running above query results in error "unknown column 't.ID'".
Then I tried another query, but that only gives me tags that are used in the results - no tags with count=0:
SELECT t.ID, t.name, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `tags` t
LEFT JOIN `item_tags` it
ON t.ID=it.IDtag
WHERE it.IDitem IN (
    SELECT it.IDitem
    FROM `tags` t
    LEFT JOIN `item_tags` it on t.ID=it.IDtag
    WHERE t.ID IN (1, 3)
    GROUP BY it.IDitem
    HAVING COUNT(*)=2
    )
GROUP BY t.ID

After a lot of thinking I devised a query that seems to work, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it:
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT t.ID AS `ID`, t.name, COUNT(*) as `count`
    FROM `tags` t
    JOIN `item_tags` it ON t.ID=it.IDtag
    WHERE it.IDitem IN (
        SELECT it.IDitem
        FROM `tags` t
        JOIN `item_tags` it ON t.ID=it.IDtag
        WHERE t.ID IN (1, 3)
        GROUP BY it.IDitem
        HAVING COUNT(*)=2
        )
    GROUP BY t.ID
    UNION
    SELECT t.ID, t.name, 0 as count
    FROM `tags` t
    ) tempTags
GROUP BY `ID`


in counting tag usage, your SELECT t.ID, t.name, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tags t LEFT JOIN item_tags it ON it.IDtag=t.ID GROUP BY t.ID; will return 1 for tags with no items.  you want COUNT(it.IDtag) (count counts rows if given * or counts non-null values if given an expression)

in getting tagged items, your query will be incorrect if there are duplicate item_tags rows; make sure those are unique (e.g. with create table item_tags (IDitem int not null, IDtag int not null, primary key (IDitem,IDtag)))

your query runs under mysql, and is known bug in mariadb, i am usure wh<t you try to as the result is a simple count the hoint table a ysth already pointed out, so why do it at all?

How many tags are there?  If under 64, let's look at representing the tags as bits in a SET or BIGINT, then doo boolean arithmetic for the query.
